# Bash script with expect ending with strange syntaxes

Tags: ubuntu, expect

Hi I made a bash script in ubuntu which checks if my set-top box is online. If not it logs into it and reboots it.

The script seems to work but it wait a bit while doing the telnet expect command after logging in. It works fine but after finising i get an unexpected end and the next ubuntu line starts with some weird syntaxes like ;80R in the beginning and during the script I also see [[24;80R

what does this mean? Is the script running fine or not?

this is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

STATUS=$(curl -m 5 -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}' http://192.168.2.9)
  if [ $STATUS -eq 200 ]; then
    echo "Got 200! All done!"
  else
    echo "Got $STATUS :( Not done yet..."
    /usr/bin/expect << EOF
    spawn telnet 192.168.2.9
    expect "*?login:"    
    send "root\r"
    expect "Password:"
    send "hello\r"
    expect -re "# ?$"
    send "echo hello world\r"
    expect -re "# ?$"
    close
EOF
fi
    echo "Finished"
```

this is the output

```
user@server-T5600:~$ /var/script/boxcheck.sh
Got 401 :( Not done yet...
spawn telnet 192.168.2.9
Trying 192.168.2.9...
Connected to 192.168.2.9.
Escape character is '^]'.

Welcome to linux for settopbox

box login: root
Password: 
Last login: Fri Feb 10 09:35:14 CET 2017 on pts/0
^[[24;80Rroot@box:~# echo hello world
hello world
root@box:~# Finished
user@server-T5600:~$ ;80R
```

what is this `^[[24;80` before root and `;80R` at the end. I would just expect a clean exit. I think the script is crappy built. I just put hello world in there as reference. But normally i put `reboot/r` in it but still the issue stays the same.

Comment: Those look like [ANSI terminal control sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) -- when you ssh into the box interactively, is there colour or does the screen clear or any other "fancy" effects? expect will just see the raw control characters.

Comment: Thia is the output trough terminal. Nothing fancy all stays the samencolor.

Comment: Let me be clear, you do not see those characters when you login interactively but you do see them from except, right?

Comment: Yes when I just use the command telnet IPAdress Then I don't see those characters.